# Exporting 3D surface from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, local-scene

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1, I created a 3D terrain surface mainly using the steps outlined here: https://sites.google.com/colby.edu/mgimond-arcgis-pro/exploring-3d-surfaces

- Created new map project
- Added elevation layer
- Inserted new local scene
- Added RGB terrain layer to local scene (click/drag to contents tab, automatically goes to 2D section
- Right click on Elevation Surface/Ground and add elevation raster again
- Unchecked World elevation and world hillshade
- Click on Ground, change vertical exaggeration to 20x, and changed elevation layer colour

Now I have an RGB surface which is still listed under "2D Objects" in the contents tab for the local scene, but I am unable to do anything with it. I can't transfer it to the "3D Objects" section, nor am I able to export it as anything other than a 2D map.

How can I export this in a format that I can 3D print? (Probably in .obj format)

This process was so much easier in ArcScene (add elevation and terrain layers, specify elevation layer, set vertical exaggeration, export as .wrl).

Comment: This creates a STL  (Lithophane) file https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-living-atlas/mapping/make-this-3d-printed-globe-please/